# Is it possible to get powershell entered code line response to coldfusion in cfexecute?

Tags: powershell, coldfusion, cfexecute

I'm trying to get Powershell's output back to ColdFusion with different attributes like errorVariable, Variable, errorFile, outputFile but with no success.

Coldfusion code -

```
<cfset hello = "hello">
<cfexecute name="C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
arguments="/c start c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\Users\raimonds\Desktop\lala.ps1 '#hello#'" 
variable="test">

<cfdump var="#test#">
```

And the powershell code -

```
param([string]$hello)

Write-Host $hello
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The syntax is a bit off. Get rid of the `start` in the argument string. It is also simpler to make powerShell.exe the executable.
2. The ["timeout"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfexecute.html) is likely causing the command to return before the output is even received. Increase it to something greater than 0 and the variable will be populated.

   > ... [Default Timeout  0] starts a process and returns immediately. ColdFusion may
   >   return control to the calling page before any program output displays.
   >   To ensure that program output displays, set the value to 2 or higher.

   Increase the timeout to something greater than 0 and you should see the result.

**NB:** Always capture any errors so the code can handle any issues accordingly.

```
<cfset inputVar = "test value here">
<cfexecute name="c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
    arguments="C:\path\to\yourScript.ps1 '#inputVar#'" 
    variable="result"
    errorvariable="err"
    timeout="2">

<cfdump var="#result#">
<cfdump var="#err#">
```

Comment: Looks good, but how can i get back the ps output to cfexecute? thank you

Comment: Not sure I follow.  The above already returns the result of `Write-Host $hello` to cfexecute. Dump `#result#` and it displays "test value here".

Comment: Okay if i want to add a text from powershell script like this - 

    param([string]$hello)
    Write-Host "$hello + is with another ps1 value"

and return to cf?

Comment: That should work fine. What happened when you tried it?